# Python multiprocessing cannot use all my cpu cores

Tags: multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to use python `multiprocessing` to create the graph dataset. The code for creating graph data with multiprocessing is as follows:

```py
import mmcv
import os
from os import path as osp
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
import pandas as pd
import TwoDimTTC
import warnings
import multiprocessing
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

def read_and_dump(idx, src_path, dst_path):
    data = mmcv.load(src_path + '/' + 'sample_infos_{}.pkl'.format(str(idx)))
    ego_velo = [data['can_bus'][14], data['can_bus'][13]]
    instance_info_list = data['instance_info']

    #### codes of constructing graph data, I omit then because of space.####

    edge_index = torch.LongTensor(edge_index).t().contiguous()
    edge_type = torch.LongTensor(edge_type)
    edge_weight = torch.FloatTensor(edge_weight)

    graph_data_dict = {
        'node_features': node_features,
        'edge_type': edge_type,
        'edge_index': edge_index,
        'edge_weight': edge_weight,
    }
    mmcv.dump(graph_data_dict, osp.join(dst_path, 'sample_infos_{}.pkl'.format(str(idx))))


def create_graph(src_path, dst_path):
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 1)
    for idx in range(len(os.listdir(src_path))):
        args = (idx, src_path, dst_path)
        pool.apply_async(func=read_and_dump, args=args)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from tqdm import tqdm
    for d in tqdm(os.listdir('nuscenes_data_pkl_split/train/')):
        src = osp.join('nuscenes_data_pkl_split/train/', d)
        dst = osp.join('nuscenes_data_pkl_split/graph_split/train/', d)
        create_graph(src_path=src, dst_path=dst)
```

However, I found that the cpu cores were not being used properly:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7nRB.png)
It seems that only two cores are running. Furthermore, the core occupancy was also weird.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKQKx.png)
You can see that the processes had been created, but they only used half of the cpu cores.

I tried printing multiprocessing.cpu_count() and it returns 32 which is correct for i9-13900K
I had tried using `multiprocessing.Process()` instead of `multiprocessing.Pool()` as:

```
def create_graph(src_path, dst_path):
     ProcessWorker = []
     for idx in range(len(os.listdir(src_path))):
         p = multiprocessing.Process(target=read_and_dump, args=(idx, src_path, dst_path))
         ProcessWorker.append(p)
         p.start()
    
     for pw in ProcessWorker:
         pw.join()
```

but the problem remains.
I also wondered if it it an operating system issue, so I tried `sudo lshw | grep core` and it returns:
`configuration: cores=24 enabledcores=24 microcode=271 threads=32`
After that I tried `lscpu -a --extended`, and the OS successfully recognizes 32 cores.

Comment: Have you checked that most of the work is really to do by the CPUs and not by input/output or GPU?

Comment: Try to calculate timings for the mmcv load and dump functions and then look at the timings for the 3 torch operations. If the mmcv operations are I/O bound (I've never used mmcv so no real idea what it does) and the torch functionality is very fast, then you can deduce that your sub-processes are I/O bound and that would explain what you're observing. It's also worth noting that neither torch nor torchvision are available for Python 3.12.0

Comment: I have checked that all the works is do by the CPUs. The GPU is not used in this procedure. And the input/output operations are `mmcv.load` and `mmcv.dump`, while they only take 0.001 seconds and the omitted codes take 100+ seconds. @Michael Butscher

Comment: I have checked the timing as your suggestion. The mmcv.load and mmcv.dump both took 0.001 seconds while the torch operations took 0.0001 seconds. By contrast, the omitted codes took 100+ seconds. During the time checking, I found something interesting. When I print the time consumption of torch operations, they show up at almost the same time intervals! It seems that the processes are created simultaneously but run sequentially? @Codist